# Importance of Inheritance in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, object, inheritance

I have implemented inheritance in python and code is working, Also, I have tried doing the same thing in other way also, I want to know where inheritance has advantage over my second way of doing the same thing.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self._a = a
        self.b = b
    def addition(self):
        return self._a+self.b

################################### Inheritance ############

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, a,b):
        super().__init__(a,b)
        print("Protected in B ",self._a)


################################### Doing same work by creating object #################

class D():
    def __init__(self, a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        d = A(self.a,self.b)
        print(d.addition())
        print("Protected in D ", d._a)
```

I'm able to call protected member of class A in both ways. Any member of A can be accessed in both ways, so, why inheritance is importance. In which scenario only inheritance will work and NOT object creation ?

Comment: *Python doesn't have access modifiers, everything is "public"*

Comment: Hi Juanpa, if everything is public, then let me know what is explained on below link - https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/classes.html?highlight=private%20members#private-variables

Comment: What do you not understand? "“Private” instance variables that cannot be accessed except from inside an object don’t exist in Python." There is no mention of access modifiers, only a convention that a single underscore and double-underscore name-mangling.

Comment: okay, so if I, change my "b" member of A class to "__b" and add one statement in class B and D i.e., "print (self.__b)" , "print(d.__b)" respectively, why these 2 will not work ? If there is any syntax issue please let me know. OR I can re-frame my question how can I access "__b" member of class A in class B and D ?

Comment: Because using two double-underscores causes *double-underscore name-mangling*. You can access the member as `._A__b`, but *you shouldn't*. Note, the purpose of this is to prevent accidental name-collisions in a subclass. Your original question seems to be about the "importance of inheritance", but that has nothing to do with what attributes you can access. You can access all attributes everywhere in Python

Comment: Inheritance is used to model particular relationships; `_`-prefixed attributes are part of the *private* implementation of the class, whether or not inheritance is involved, and should not be used outside of the class. Whether to use inheritance or *composition* (which is what `D` uses) is a separate issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that your example showcases the power of inheritance.

1. The 2nd example doesn't look very OOP-like. I rarely see object creation in the constructor *unless* it is an instance variable or a static variable.
2. Not every base class will have all the fields that the subclass has. For example, an `Animal` class may be super generic, but as more classes like `Tiger` extends it, `Tiger` will have more tiger properties (and not have the basic same ones as the `Animal` class).

To focus back on your question, the 2nd example, will require you to use `self.d` if you want to access the protected variable `_a`, unless you want to do `d = D()` and then `d.a`, which isn't very protected. You are creating an object within `D`, whereas you are still setting up the blueprint for the class in the 1st example. That might not be what you are looking to do, as the 2nd example with the object creation looks like it could be the driver class.